# Algorithm complexity asymptote graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, curve, asymptotic-complexity

I'm preparing a C++ project , which I have to calcute many algorithms complexity big-O and compare it with the theoric value on a graph. I made a time function that calculate the time execution of an algorithm but I didn't find a way to calculte the complexity and draw the curve using time T and Input N.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Your program is measuring the time for a particular value of n=n0. Where as the running time, say T=O(n) is the plot for n (=min_value to max_value). If you run your program for all those n (=min_value to max_value) and calculate time for each input, and then plot (y-axis=time Vs x-axis=n), that should be similar to the graph for theoretical complexity (in this case T=O(n) is of the form y=mx, where m is a constant and affects only the slope of the line, you can consider m=1 for your calculations.

Comment: How to make it with C++ code please ?

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell: If you defined theoretical complexity T(n) all you have to do is to execute test x times for given range of n: n1, ..., nx and measure time of each test. Then you choose median nm from your set of n1, ..., nx and compute coefficient c, defined as: c = t(nm)/T(nm). t(nm) is measured time for median of n (nm), T(nm) is calculated teoretical complexity for nm.
Next, for each of your n, compute coefficient q, which is coefficient of consistency of theoretical and experimental complexity of your algorithm:

[image: Coefficient of consistency of theoretical and experimental complexity]

Finally you may draw plot of q(n) which is asymptote graph and it should converges asymptotically to 1. If your graph asymptotically goes below 1 theoretical complexity is overestimated, if goes above 1 complexity is underestimated.